# Does the ordering of encryption and hashing matter?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, hash

I am now learning keyed hash function, where A and B share a secret key k. I want to know if the ordering of encryption E and hashing H matters? i.e. Is there any difference between H ◦ Ek (m)  and Ek ◦ H (m) ?

Comment: Also, more info http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac

Comment: Combining hashing and encryption is relatively rare. In most cases we combine a MAC (possibly hash based, like HMAC) with encryption. In that case the correct order is encrypt-then-mac.

Comment: I think I didn't use the right keywords to search, so I was not able to find useful information. Thanks a lot for the replies. The link is so useful! And sorry for asking a duplicated question.